# In MS Word, when pasting contents containing numbered lists, how can I prevent these lists automatically merged?

Tags: ms-word

For example, there is a table in my doc shown as below:
[image: img1]
In *Table1*, there are 3 numbered lists. When I choose the whole table, copy it, and paste it, I get this:
[image: img2]
In the new table, let's say *Table1a*, there are 3 numbered lists, each of which is merged with lists in *Table1*. Lists in *Table1a* are numbered continuously after lists in *Table1*.
My question is: how can I prevent lists merged when pasting. Thus, when pasting there is no relation between lists in *Table1a* and *Table1*, and I can get:
[image: img3]
Thanks for any solution and discuss.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Ike I post the question on ms forum too, and solve the problem by multilevel list. The solution is posted as an answer below.

Comment: This isn’t a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multilevel list solves my problem. Here is how it works.

1. Create a new multilevel list. For level 1, make numbering empty. For level 2, use 1, 2, 3, ... as numbering.
2. In Table1 in my first pic, set Text1, Text2, Text3 formatted in multilevel list created in step 1.
3. Set all cells from Text1-1 to Text3-3 formatted in multilevel list created in step 1. Make them be level 2.
4. Now feel free to copy and paste the table. The tables and lists will be the same as shown in my third pic. Since all the contents are still managed by numbered lists, inserting or deleting a row does not require any manual modification on numbers. When cells of several rows, left column are merged, cells of the same rows, right column are automatically treated as a level 2 list, numbered in 1, 2, 3, ... When copying and pasting, left columns of tables are merged into one multilevel list (level 1), right columns remain seperate level 2 lists.

I also post the question on MS forum, and get the suggestion of multilevel list there. Visit https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/in-ms-word-when-pasting-contents-containing/c823061b-352d-4ece-b30a-05c8c5afb851 if you are interested.